# Key vs ID/Name?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I do not want to create an autogenerated key for my entities so I specify my own:

```
Entity employee = Entity.newBuilder().setKey(makeKey("Employee", "bobby"))
        .addProperty(makeProperty("fname", makeValue("fname").setIndexed(false)))
        .addProperty(makeProperty("lname", makeValue("lname").setIndexed(false)))    
        .build();

CommitRequest request = CommitRequest.newBuilder()
    .setMode(CommitRequest.Mode.NON_TRANSACTIONAL)
    .setMutation(Mutation.newBuilder().addInsert(employee))
    .build();
datastore.commit(request);
```

When I check to see what the entity looks like it looks like this:

[image]

Why is this auto-generated key generated if I specified my own key (bobby)? It seems bobby was also created, but now I have bobby and this autogenerated key. What is the difference between the key and id/name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the url-safe version of your key, suitable for use in links. Use [`KeyFactory.stringToKey`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory#stringToKey(java.lang.String)) to convert it to an actual key, and you'll see that it contains your string name.

Answer (score 4):

You can't specify your own key, keys actually contain information necessary for the datastore operation. This note in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#retrieving_entities) gives you an idea:

> Note: The URL-safe string looks cryptic, but it is not encrypted! It
>   can easily be decoded to recover the original entity's kind and
>   identifier:
>
> ```
> key = Key(urlsafe=url_string)
> kind_string = key.kind()
> ident = key.id()
> ```
>
> If you use such URL-safe keys, don't use sensitive data such as email
>   addresses as entity identifiers. (A possible solution would be to use
>   the MD5 hash of the sensitive data as the identifier. This stops third
>   parties, who can see the encrypted keys, from using them to harvest
>   email addresses, though it doesn't stop them from independently
>   generating their own hash of a known email address and using it to
>   check whether that address is present in the Datastore.)

What [you can specify](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#numeric_keys) is the `ID` portion of the key, either as a number or as a string:

> A key is a series of kind-ID pairs. You want to make sure each entity
>   has a key that is unique within its application and namespace. An
>   application can create an entity without specifying an ID; the
>   Datastore automatically generates a numeric ID. If an application
>   picks some IDs "by hand" and they're numeric and the application lets
>   the Datastore generate some IDs automatically, the Datastore might
>   choose some IDs that the application already used. To avoid, this, the
>   application should "reserve" the range of numbers it will use to
>   choose IDs (or use string IDs to avoid this issue entirely).

Answer (score 1):

What you create with `makeKey("Employee", "bobby")` is a key for an Entity with the entity name `Employee` and the name `bobby`. What you see as Key in the datastore viewer is a representation for exactly that.

Generally speaking a key always consists of

- optional parent key (with entity type and name/id)
- entity type
- entity name/id

Maybe someone here can tell you how to decode the key into its components but rest asured that you're doing everything right and the behavior is as expected.